# Merge Update and Remove Multiple values in a csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I need to merge two .csv files into a third file which contains update values if the ID column matches.
When there is the same row in both files, the second csv file should be used. Each file contains an ID in the first column.
[CSV table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBcfk.png)

```
csv1=pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
csv2=pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")

csv1.update(csv2)
csv_temp = pd.concat([csv1, csv2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Product ID', 'Product', 'Product Colour']).reset_index(drop=True)
csv3 = csv_temp.drop_duplicates(subset=['Product ID', 'Product', 'Product Colour']).reset_index(drop=True)

csv3.to_csv("csv3.csv", index=False)
```

I am using python3 and panda libraries

Answer (score 0):

You should set the two dataframes **index** as the product ID while reading your CSV files using index_col parameter of read_csv function [(read_csv doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
This is important because the update function will use it to match rows in the second file.

Your example uses row number as the index, if the product to update is located in another row in the second csv it won't work.

Here is a sample code I used to test it out :

```
index1 = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'EEE']
col11 = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'EEE']
col21 = ['green', 'yellow', 'red', 'EEE']

index2 = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'FFF']
col12 = ['Kiwi', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'FFF']
col22 = ['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'FFF']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col11, col21)), index=index1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col12, col22)), index=index2)

# Update first df using values in the second one
df1.update(df2)
# Merging the two df for rows only in one file and not the other one
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

I then get :

```
AAA    Kiwi   green
BBB  Banana  yellow
CCC  Orange  orange
EEE     EEE     EEE
FFF     FFF     FFF
```

AAA and CCC products are in both df and correctly updated.
EEE product was only in the first one and FFF product was only in the second one ; they are both in the resulted df.